# SQL Query A->B->A->B->A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns and want to query like A->B->A->B->A......until end. At one position A does not have B that is the end. Please guide how to query to get the results.

```
A                                       B
----------------------------------------------------------------------
{07906439-7636-462D-95AE-B0D7683814A8}  {69DA38DB-BA4F-4F34-9DCB-4F1DF7C353FD}
{69DA38DB-BA4F-4F34-9DCB-4F1DF7C353FD}  {0460261B-833E-4FCD-981B-26A7846B593D}
{0460261B-833E-4FCD-981B-26A7846B593D}  {713607FA-32ED-4AFD-83AF-5CA346A1A019}
{713607FA-32ED-4AFD-83AF-5CA346A1A019}
```

Comment: Your question is not really answerable unless there exists a column which can be used to order things the way you want.  So...is there such a column?

Comment: Look for Recursive CTE's or hierarchical relationships inside SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unless there are cycles (not present in OP's sample data), there *is* an ordering. We can take the transitive closure of the binary relation "Given rows `x` and `y`, `x.A = y.B`"

Comment: What data do you want as the output of your query?

Comment: @Caleth Look at Michael's answer below for what I would have posted, had there been an ordering column.  It is a meaningless query though, without a column to use for ordering, because then the order wouldn't be guaranteed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You don't **need** a synthesised order. Look at user2321864's answer. OP just needs to specify what they mean by "the results"

Comment: Do you haz the codez?

Answer (score 3):

In below query you assign 0, 2, 4... to column A and 1, 3, 5... to column B, then you just `union all` columns with these ranks and sort by them, this way you will achieve alternating records. Note that I used `order by (select null)`, which is physical order of the table, you might want to introduce some column which will guarantee, that result will be invariant.

```
select * from (
select [A],row_number() over (order by (select null))*2-2 [rn] from MY_TABLE
union all
select [B],row_number() over (order by (select null))*2-1 [rn] from MY_TABLE
) [a] order by [rn]
```

Answer (score 1):

try recursive CTE's... something like the following

```
with temp as (
  select A, B, 0 as Level
  from Table1
  where B is null

  union all

  select t.A, t.B, x.Level + 1
  from Table1 t
  inner join temp x
    on t.B = x.A
)
select *
from temp;
```